# How to unmount dvd (external usb) via eject button on device?

Tags: linux, mount, dvd, raspbian, umount

I have an problem with my external usb Dvd-Drive. Everything works fine, the mount works, unmount or eject via shell works. But if I press the eject button on the device it just eject the dvd but does not unmount it. My best solution for this problem is to execute a script with a shortcut on the keyboard. But this isn't really satisfying. 
Are they any options to solve this problem with the normal eject button on the DVD-Drive?

Thanks for u help.

EDIT:
Output 'udevadm info --version'

```
175
```

Output 'cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules | grep DISK_EJECT_REQUEST'

```
ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}=="?*", RUN+="cdrom_id --eject-media $tempnode", GOTO="cdrom_end"
```

Output 'uname -a'

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Output 'udevadm monitor' by insert (all 4 entries) and remove (no entry)

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[682164.008310] change   /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [682164.057144] change   /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
KERNEL[682174.005812] change   /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [682174.655906] change   /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a long standing "bug" in udisks which causes this to happen. It's actually "normal" behaviour for udisks - optical drives are a bit of an edge case where, though the media is removed, the drive is still present. This was been reported in the ubuntu bugtracker some time ago and a workaround using udev was suggested:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1168742

You already have a script which will unmount the drive - to get this to run when the disc is ejected add the following to a udev rule, e.g. /etc/udev/rules.d/70-unmount-cd.rules

```
KERNEL=="sr0", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/path/to/your/unmount/script.sh"
```

There's a load of good info in the above link, so check that out too.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, did is exact the information I was looking for. Currently I can't try your approach but I will report the result later.

Comment: Best of luck SimonA! Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: So.. after some problems i'm able to execute the script via  /etc/udev/rules.d/70-unmount-cd.rules. My line is:"KERNEL=="sr0", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="BD-MLT UJ240AS  ", ACTION=="change", RUN+="..path to script...$". First I got problems by execute the script "Exec format error" in syslog. Write "#!/bin/sh" in the first line of the script solve this problem.

Comment: Now the script executes by different actions (e.g. mount) but it does not start the script if I press the button... may the "ACTION" need to be modified?

Comment: i also try to trigger/see some events with "udevadm monitor --environment --udev" but by pressing the button nothing happens... :(.

Comment: Hmm, it's strange that you're not seeing any udev events using udevadm monitor, that would certainly explain why the rule isn't being invoked. If you just run "udevadm monitor" then insert/remove the CD do you see a kernel event, followed shortly after by a udev event?

Comment: Additionally, which distro are you running? Raspbian? Could you post the outputs of `cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules | grep DISK_EJECT_REQUEST`,
`udevadm info --version` and `uname -a` please? Also, when you run your `udevadm monitor` experiments, make sure there's actually some media in the CD drive!

Comment: That is really strange. "udevadm monitor" invoke an 'change' if I insert a dvd. But still nothing if i remove it via hardware eject button.

Comment: I edit my first post for the different outputs.

Comment: The plot thickens, since 60-cdrom_id.rules appears to be fine, and you have udev change events! To make sure your script is actually being run could you change it so it does something obvious, for example `touch /var/log/thisworks`? Also, best post the contents of your script - I'm running out of ideas so falling back to the old adage of saying there's probably some configuration error somewhere!

Comment: Additionally, could you append the contents of `udevadm info --name=/dev/sr0 --attribute-walk` to your post? I've tested this solution using my SATA DVD drive not USB as you're using, so it'd be good to see your device chain.